# Lower-bound on the size of the largest eigenvalues of the laplacian matrix in random graphs

Tags: probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-graphs

In a random graph $G(n,p)$, with Laplacian matrix $L = A - D$, for adjacency matrix $A$ and degree matrix $D$.

Is there a way to lower-bound the value of the biggest eigenvalue for the Laplacian matrix? Something that looks like the following: 
$$
Prob(\lambda_\max(L) > \lambda_0) \geq \delta
$$

Note: I know of "Convergence in Probability" results. For example, [Ding and Jian, 2010 (Theorem 1)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.2608.pdf) have: 
$$
\frac{ \lambda_\max(L) }{\sqrt{n \log n}} \overset{P} \rightarrow \sqrt{2}
$$
which I don't think it gives what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't it give you this though, I concluded the opposite:

That $\left[ \frac{\lambda_{max}(L_n)}{\sqrt{n \log n}} \right]$ converges in probability to $\sqrt{2}$ (as $n$ goes to infinity) implies that for any $\epsilon, \tau > 0$ there exists an $n$ such that

$\mathbb{P}\left[ \frac{\lambda_{max}(L_n)}{\sqrt{n \log n}} \right] \geq \sqrt{2} - \epsilon]$ $\geq 1-\tau$ and

$\mathbb{P}\left[ \frac{\lambda_{max}(L_n)}{\sqrt{n \log n}} \right] \geq \sqrt{2} + \epsilon]$ $\leq \tau$.

So for any fixed $\epsilon >0$ and $\lambda_0 \leq \sqrt{(2-\epsilon) n \log n}$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that the inequality

$\mathbb{P}\left[{\lambda_{max}(L_n)} \geq {\lambda_0} \right]$ $\geq \delta$

holds; in fact $\delta$ can be close to 1. And for $\lambda_0 \geq \sqrt{(2+\epsilon) n \log n}$ there exists no such $\delta >0$ such that the above ineqaulity holds.